# How to push element attribute value into javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html structure. Here, i have created two attributes for each element. How to push attribute value into an array (like this structure, [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[0,2],[2,2],[1,3],[1,4]])?

```
<div id="demo">
     <div data-floor="1" data-floor-sub="0">Div1</div>
     <div data-floor="2" data-floor-sub="0">Div2</div>
     <div data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="0">Div3</div>
     <div data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="1">Div4</div>
     <div data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="2">Div5</div>
     <div data-floor="4" data-floor-sub="0">Div6</div>
     <div data-floor="5" data-floor-sub="0">Div7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
var multiDimArray = $('#demo div').map(function() {
  var innerArray = [];
  innerArray.push([$(this).data('floor'), $(this).data('floor-sub')]);
  return innerArray;
}).get();

console.log(multiDimArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div data-floor="1" data-floor-sub="0">Div1</div>
  <div data-floor="2" data-floor-sub="0">Div2</div>
  <div data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="0">Div3</div>
  <div data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="1">Div4</div>
  <div data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="2">Div5</div>
  <div data-floor="4" data-floor-sub="0">Div6</div>
  <div data-floor="5" data-floor-sub="0">Div7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to store value, like this structure [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [4,0], [5,0].... @AmmarCSE

Comment: @Sathya, my answer gives an array of arrays, isnt that what you wanted?

Comment: your answer is showing like [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 5, 0]. But i want to store like this, [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [4,0], [5,0]. Is there anyway to get result like that way?

Comment: Thanks... @RickHitchcock